# Resource merging during gradle builds with different approaches

Tags: android, gradle, android-resources, android-productflavors, source-sets

As we know there are two ways of having separate `res` directories for each `productFlavor` or `buildType`.

**First Approach** is by having separate directories under the `src` folder e.g. `src\flavor1\res`, `src\flavor2\res` etc.

**Second Approach** is specifying the `res` directory under `sourceSets` in the `build.gradle` like

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        res.srcDirs    = ['res']
    }
    dev {
        res.srcDirs    = ['res-dev']
    }
}
```

I know for sure that resource merging will happen in the *first approach* and any missing resource in the separate directory for flavor will be picked up from the `main`'s sourceSet.

**Question is about *second approach* above.**

Will resource merging happen in the same way as it happens with the first approach using separate folders? Here i am explicitly going to assign a separate directory. Does it still fallback to main for resources not found in the specified directory?

I ask this because of the example in [THIS LINK on http://tools.android.com/](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-merging) where towards the end of the article it shows `'src/main/res'` being explicitly added as follows:

> ```
> android.sourceSets {
>    main.res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/main/res2']
> }
> ```

Has anyone done this and knows if the resource merging will still happen if i just give the additional directory and not main as an additional one? will it fallback to the main directory for missing resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I tried out for myself with each of the above scenarios. Findings were as follows:

1. There is no need to specify the `src\main\res` directory. The fallback happens in both approach to the main res directory.
2. This worked absolutely well for both `res` and `assets` folder. And I assume it will work exactly same for other folders too. I did not need those so havent tried. But, I cant think of any reason why they wont work when `res` and `assets` folders do.

Hence, it works as expected.